# Is there a name for equal cardinality (between bijective non-proper sets)?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Is there a name for equal cardinality (between bijective non-proper sets)?

Answer (score 1):

When two sets have the same cardinality, they are called [equinumerous, equipollent or equipotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity). The extra details in your question don't lead to why other terminology is necessary.

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Comment: @JairTaylor I've seen all three of these. E.g. [Suppes' book uses "equipollent"](https://books.google.com/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=equipollent+set&source=bl&ots=xyloc7rgxN&sig=ACfU3U3VSzTC8w_DpfIV4hyyWYu23vrVcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVi9e0w8P1AhW7J0QIHVJJC7kQ6AF6BAg7EAM#v=onepage&q=equipollent%20set&f=false).

Comment: Is to say that they are equivalent less popular?

Comment: @Hermis14 That would be much too ambiguous, considering other equivalence relations of interest.

Comment: @J.G. I agree with you but I've seen many other references use the term to mean the same cardinality. I was just curious.